# Line spacing for only certain pages

Tags: line-spacing

I want line spacing only for certain pages and keep the default for other pages. For example, I want no line spacing for certificate pages and line spacing of 1.5 (MS Word equivalent) for chapter pages. How to get this done?

Comment: Is is possible to use separate files for the chapters and the certificates?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can load the `setspace` package. With it you can then set the spacing for certain sections by enclosing them in its own environment by using the tags `\begin{spacing}{<length>} ... \end{spacing}`.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

Cras efficitur dui purus, at molestie lacus mattis et. Fusce finibus augue vitae risus pharetra, eget fermentum mauris consequat. Vestibulum in blandit dui. Ut et ante sed sem viverra tempus. Suspendisse tincidunt vulputate lacus, ut finibus massa dapibus ut. Nulla lectus tortor, faucibus vel eleifend ut, suscipit quis erat. Vestibulum laoreet ex in imperdiet laoreet. In at tellus non felis feugiat vestibulum. Nullam a lacus tortor. Sed et ligula lacus. Quisque eget molestie nisi.
\\
\begin{spacing}{1.5}
Phasellus lacinia efficitur tempus. In vitae pharetra mauris, quis pharetra lectus. Sed pharetra, purus in condimentum condimentum, augue nibh pellentesque eros, at posuere mi lacus eu risus. Phasellus condimentum, sapien at porttitor fermentum, lorem dolor malesuada odio, vel sodales ipsum sapien et augue.  neque id consequat. Quisque est metus, tincidunt lacinia dui sit amet, congue auctor arcu
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

If you use this a lot, you can set a new command in the preamble (before `\begin{document}`) like

```
\newcommand{\bsp}{\begin{spacing}{1.5}}
\newcommand{\esp}{\end{spacing}}
```

so you can just type those commands, or enter a parameter by writing `\newcommand{\bsp}{\begin{spacing}{#1}}`, so in the document you can type `\bsp{1.5}` or `\bsp{2}`.